# contains function in Xpath

Tags: java, xml, string, xpath, string-function

I am using java to process Xpath for my project. I have and XMl similar to this
'''

```
<Tag1>
   <Tag2>
       <Name>ABC\Test</Name>
       <value>10</value>
   </Tag2>
   <Tag2>
       <Name>ABC\Test\test1</Name>
       <value>112</value>
   </Tag2>  
<Tag1>
```

'''
My requirement is to write an Xpath that works for all similar xml to get the "Value" where name is Test. In the above example ABC in ABC\test can be anything(i.e. in one set of xml it will be abc in other xyz) so cannot use strict compare like:

```
//Tag2[Name[text()="text"]/value/text()
```

This will fail as the exact match us not there. I also tried the contains function like:

```
//Tag2[contains(Name,"test")]/value/text()
```

This case works but it return both the value node.

Is there any other function with which i can achieve this. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can't replicate the problem; I get `112` as the output with the second expression (with `contains()`.

Answer (score 1):

(1) The input XML is not well-formed. So I fixed it.

(2) XML is case sensitive, so looking for the "test" string will not find "Test".

> XML

```
<Tag1>
    <Tag2>
        <Name>ABC\Test</Name>
        <value>10</value>
    </Tag2>
    <Tag2>
        <Name>ABC\Test\test1</Name>
        <value>112</value>
    </Tag2>
</Tag1>
```

> XPath

```
/Tag1/Tag2[contains(Name,"test")]/value/text()
```